# Laravel Nova Observe not connecting to tenant database

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have a multi tenant App. My system database I have models- User, Billing, FrontEnd ... and using policies I'm able to show, hide and prevent viewing and actions by tenant.

Each tenant has a database with models- Member, Event, Item ...
I set each model database based on the `Auth::user()->dbname` in the `_construct` method. This allows me to set my dbname to a clients database for tech support.

```
class Item extendsw Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        if(Auth::user()->dbname) {
            Config::set('database.connections.tenant.database', auth()->user()->dbname);
             $this->connection = 'tenant';
        }
    }
```

This all works as planned until I add and Observer for a client model e.g. Member

I now get an error on any Observer call.

> Trying to get property on non object Auth::user()->dbname.

Where should I be registering the Observer? I tried **`AppServiceProvider`** and **`NovaServiceProvider`**.

Answer (score 0):

I think that happens because the observer instantiates your User model before the request cycle has started and that means that your `User` instance does not exist yet neither has been bound in the Auth facade.

Thus, `Auth::user()` returns `null` and you are trying to get a property from it. 
A way to solve the issue may be to check if the user instance exists or not:

```php
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    if (optional(Auth::user())->dbname !== null) {
        Config::set('database.connections.tenant.database', auth()->user()->dbname);
         $this->connection = 'tenant';
    }
}
```

The `optional` helper return the value of the accessed property (`dbname` in your case) if and only if the argument is not null, otherwise the whole call will return a null value instead throwing an exception.

If that is not the case, maybe update the question with the error stacktrack and the code/action that triggers the error